# RegEx in Microsoft Word Find/Replace to locate an unescaped semi-colon in index markers

Tags: regex, microsoft-word-2010, find-and-replace

I've got **Find/Replace** open, under **More** I have **Use wildcards** checked.

I have a LOT of index markers in my document, and I want to find semicolons inside the index markers that are NOT escaped. I want to only find semicolon (**;**) not a semicolon preceded by a backslash (**\;**), there may be more than one semicolon that needs to be located in a single index marker, and I want to add the backslash in front of any semicolons that don't already have the backslash in front of them.

I've reproduced a couple of my index markers below.

```
{ XE "afráðskollr:damage-head\; burden-head\; a man who causes suffering and setbacks" }
{ XE "ganimaðr:impetuous man; hothead" }
```

I've tried experimenting, but I am not getting even the search part right. Heaven help me when I try to replace a plain semicolon with an escaped semicolon! I'm probably having issues between my knowledge of real RegEx vs. what MS Word is using here.

Any advice would be most welcome!

Comment: The regex to find a semicolon not preceded by a slash is: `(?<!\\);` but I'm not sure MSWord supports that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MS Word doesn't use normal regex as already mentioned on the comments by @Toto. Read the following article, [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm), on how to use wildcards in MS Word.

Based on the article, use the following:

- Find what: `([!\\])(;)`
- Replace with: `\1^92\2`

**Eplanation:**

- `([!\\])(;)`: finds semi-colons not preceded by a backlash `[!\\]`. The preceding character and the semi-colon are captured separately.
- `\1^92\2`: replaces what we found with the preceding character, then the backlash `^92` followed by the semicolon.

In case you have LibreOffice Writer installed on your machine, you can use the regex `(?<!\\);` (as advised on the comments) as it supports proper regular expressions find and replace.

Comment: Since I also have a mort of semicolons outside of the index tags, I'm trying to get it to JUST search inside the tags.  I tried this:

( XE*[!\\])(;)(*")

Unfortunately it's grabbing the { XE through the next semicolon, whether its inside index marker or not.

Comment: @ChristieWard There are no lookarounds in MS Word like in other apps with regex capabilities. They would have made it easier to find/replace. What you can try is to find out the style of your index(es). Then, use it as (an additional) condition for your `Find what`. This will allow to search only the indexes (hopefully if there are the only ones with that particular style).

Comment: Word index markers are fields. A search for { XE doesn't get a hit, because the { probably holds the field definition and whatnot where we can't see it. Similarly, I can't get search to recognize the field closing }